# Retrieve documents that store time-series data knowing only previous end and next start?

Tags: mongodb

I am storing time-series data across multiple fixed-sized, pre-allocated documents. When one fills up, another is created. Each document has two pre-calculated values:

- prevEnd (stores the value in last index of previous document's values)
- nextStart (stores the value in the next document's first index)

I want to rely on these pre-aggregated values to find a range of documents when searching by a time range. The following example uses integers in place of timestamps or dates for clarity.

Question: How can I select the two documents below knowing only the time range of interest (111-114)?

```
{
"prevEnd"; 107,
"nextStart": 110,
"time" : [ 
    NumberLong(107)
    NumberLong(108)
    NumberLong(109)
]
},

//-----------------Select Start

{
    "prevEnd": 109,
    "nextStart": 113,
    "time" : [ 
        NumberLong(110), 
        NumberLong(111), 
        NumberLong(112),
    ]
},


{
    "prevEnd": 112,
    "nextStart": 116,
    "time" : [ 
        NumberLong(113), 
        NumberLong(114), 
        NumberLong(115)
    ]
},

//-----------------Select End

{
    "prevEnd": 115,
    "nextStart": 99999999999999999999999999999999,
    "time" : [ 
        NumberLong(116), 
        NumberLong(117), 
        NumberLong(118)
    ]
}
```

Comment: How/where are these pre-calculated values stored?  The "example" looks like a list of dictionaries; if so, are they in order?

Comment: Each one is a document. Should have separated them / given ID to each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following find() call will work:

```
db.collection.find({"time": {"$elemMatch": {$gt: 111, $lt: 114}}})
```

because it uses the `$elemMatch` operator to match the documents which contain a time field with at least one element that matches **both** the upper and lower limits.

But since your question explicitly refers to prevEnd and nextStart I suspect you are looking for a solution which filters on those attribuites. For example:

```
db.collection.find({$or: [{"prevEnd": {$gt: 111}}, {"nextStart": {$gt: 111}}], "prevEnd": {$lt: 114}})
```

Comment: What is the type of `db`?